# Which will be faster for my site's functionality - Ajax or Non-Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to display the result of a database query in a table on my site. There could be up to 1000 rows of 10 columns to display after the query (although this would normally be less due to filter selections).

I'm undecided whether I should:

- make an ajax request that would return a JSON string which I would then use client-side to construct the table, or
- make a normal synchronous request and have the page constructed server-side (PHP)

I'm assuming that the server-side method would be a little faster, but I have very little to go on and the client-side code to construct the table may be a little more convoluted than the PHP.

Which method do people think would result in the results table being displayed quicker?

Any other (constructive :) ) thoughts would be welcome.

Many thanks

Comment: dude, this is arguable ... benchmark both approaches will give u better answer

Comment: Are your results paginated or do you want those thousand results visible in one page only ?

Comment: At the moment, not paginated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to measure.

Aspects:

- Ajax typically involves an extra request, which takes time and generates load on the server. If you have a high load server, you might want to balance the number of requests to the number of bytes per request
- Use of your site: If users typically only see the first 10 objects, only 5% of users advance to the second page and 0.5% page down further, the reasoning is different from a scenario where 80% of users page down to page 5
- You can also think of something from both worlds: Transmit 50 rows, display 10 and only after the 6th paging down request more via ajax

What do you want to optimize? Server load? Client responsiveness? Bytes transmitted? Transmission time?

Comment: I don't have too much experience, but I don't think the server load will be an issue. I'm not worried about it being overloaded. I also don't think that it requires the maximum client-side responsiveness of some apps. The user will click a button and wait for info to be displayed. So I think I want to maximise transmission time in this particular case. ie the load time of the results table.

Comment: @Joe: Transmission time is different than load time. To optimize for transmission you would need to lower the amount of data for the response (hence JSON would be the better solution). On the other hand, to optimize for the load time you should consider both, because if you construct the markup on the server side you will have to transfer much more data. However, if you construct the markup client side, then for sure it is going to take much more time than doing it server side.

Comment: I'd say it doesn't make much difference if you transmit 10 or 50 rows - 1000 however might be prohibitive. The most time spent in webapplications is typically for the request itself. E.g. adding a second request is more expensive than transmitting 2-10 times the amount of data. (within certain limits that is, but I hope you get the point). "Measure!" is key

Comment: OK. I see that I'll definitely have to do some benchmarking here. First time for everything :) Interesting that it will depend on the 'average use' of the app. Will people generally use the filters before they search, or will they just download the whole lot.

Answer (score 2):

Performance is tricky, and it rarely correct just to ask "which is fastest".

You will see different performance characteristics as the number of users grows. If you do the majority of processing on the server, then as more users are added the server gets busier. If you offload some of the work to the client then as more users come along you get the benefit of some work being done on their machines. So in effect you will see two different performance curves that may well cross at some point.

I would start like this:

a). Don't target as fast a possible. Take to an extreme this approach would result in unmaintainable code, possibly with bits written in assembler, running on a Blue-gene server. That's a joke by the way, but the point is that at some point the performance is "good enough". Get explicit requirements, support X users, with this response time, doing that work ... Include requirements concerning usability. You may well be trading off performance for ease of use.

b). Try the approach that gives the user experience that you want, test it. Suppose you get nice sub-second response (or whatever your target may be) for a reasonable user population then fine.

c). One of the beauties of the Ajax approach is that it's open to lots of benefits from pre-fetching and caching. Is you application likely to benefit from that? In which case the  perceived performance of the app may be made good without "optimising" away the Ajax stuff.

Comment: Interesting point. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Regarding point c), so basically the only part of the page that is having to be changed is the new markup. All the images and other parts of the page don't change.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the maintainability, I missed that in my answer.

Comment: @Joe, yes, you don't re-serve the "content", but in some cases you don't even re-serve the data either. Consider browsing a directory tree, you can cache the upper levels, so any time we re=populate the tree we already have the data. Much less load on the server.

Comment: In your experience, is it easier to maintain a PHP page, or the JavaScript (using jQuery) that would be used to construct the table? I guess that depends on the individual and might be a bit of an open ended question. Possibly for me, I would be able to see at a glance how the PHP was working, whereas I would have the table constructing javascript functions on another page with the HTML to be inserted mixed up with the JavaScript which might make it less readable.

Comment: A really good question ;-) There is a serious learning curve with JavScript. You can structure a suitable separation of concerns, the code can be maintainable, but it's clearly more complex than just PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The second option (i.e. constructing the table server side) is going to be the fastest solution!

By returning a JSON and then building up the table you will waste time, with:

1. `json_encode`
2. iterating over the JSON to construct the markup

Comment: not really, data transfer could be the bottle-neck

Comment: @ajreal: Data transfer will be faster than any kind of operation you will do client side to construct the markup.

Comment: -1 @ajreal, sorry, but this just need not be the case. Consider the relative performance curves as number of users increase.

Comment: @djna: Thanks for your point of view. However, in reality, I think the JSON solution will never outspeed the server side solution. A request will be made to the server either way, an iteration will be done on the server either by constructing the markup or building the JSON with `json_encode`.

Comment: @Shef depending upon exactly what you are building, a JSON string may be much more terse than a fully marked up page. If we can offload the final formatting to the Browser as the number of users increases we may see interesting effects. Look at Stack Overflow itself, we have lots of little updates happening asynchronously. The perceived performance is very high.

Comment: @djna: Handling small markup operations client-side is not even near to handling 1000s of records. So, if you can, benchmark it, sure you can convince me. I have never seen/achieved this costly operation work better/faster in client side.